# System.UnauthorizedAccessException when trying to accept audio call in Lync 2013

Tags: c#, winforms, lync

I have a problem with my Lync client that I am designing. I am running Lync 2013 in UI Suppression mode and I am able to send/receive IM's just fine, and begin audio calls. But a problem occurs when I try to receive an audio conversation from someone else. I get a System.UnauthorizedAccessException when I try to call this line of code:

```
conv.Modalities[ModalityTypes.AudioVideo].BeginConnect(ModalityCallback, asyncState);
```

It runs perfectly fine otherwise, and the call goes through okay and I can hear and talk to the other side just fine, but my User Interface freezes and I can't control anything due to this error. Even when the other side hangs up, I have to kill the process in Task Manager.

Here is my InitiateAVStream method, based on the [MSDN Join Lync conversation example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj937250.aspx#bk_example1):

```
    public bool InitiateAVStream()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("InitiateAVStream");
        if (conv.State == ConversationState.Terminated)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (conv.Modalities[ModalityTypes.AudioVideo].CanInvoke(ModalityAction.Connect))
        {
            conv.Modalities[ModalityTypes.AudioVideo].ModalityStateChanged += _AVModality_ModalityStateChanged;
            conv.Modalities[ModalityTypes.AudioVideo].ActionAvailabilityChanged += _AVModality_ActionAvailabilityChanged;

            //Accept the notification. If Lync UI is enabled, incoming call notification is closed.
            conv.Modalities[ModalityTypes.AudioVideo].Accept();

            //Connect the AV modality and begin to send and received AV stream.
            object[] asyncState = { conv.Modalities[ModalityTypes.AudioVideo], "CONNECT" };
            try
            {
                conv.Modalities[ModalityTypes.AudioVideo].BeginConnect(ModalityCallback, asyncState);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
```

The output message:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in Microsoft.Lync.Model.dll 
at Microsoft.Office.Uc.ModalityClass.Connect(ModalityConnectOptions _options, Object _modalityCallback, Object _state)
at Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation.Modality.BeginConnect_private(ModalityConnectOptions options, AsyncCallback modalityCallback, Object state)
at Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation.Modality.BeginConnect(AsyncCallback modalityCallback, Object state)
at UIPrototype.MeetingForm.InitiateAVStream() in c:\Users\morrissi\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\UIPrototype\UIPrototype\MeetingForm.cs:line 758
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated. And it's strange to me that it only occurs when I try accepting an incoming audio call. Everything else works fine. I have not started work on video calls yet, but I will once I get audio working.

Thanks

Edit:

Replacing BeginConnect with BeginRetrieve still throws the same error and produces the same results. Still not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. Apparently when you are connecting just an audio call, the only line you need is

```
conv.Modalities[ModalityTypes.AudioVideo].Accept();
```

You do not need to call BeginConnect to connect the audio. Removing BeginConnect prevents the error from being thrown and the audio connects just fine still. BeginConnect is used to connect video.

My problem with the form not loading completely and freezing is unrelated, it appears. That is being caused because I am trying to create a new form within ConversationManager_ConversationAdded. If I try creating a new form on a button click, it loads just fine and works, but it seems to be the event that is preventing it from working properly.

I'm not good enough at this to recognize when an error is being caused by Lync or C# yet.

Comment: I still don't get why the MSDN suggested approach does not actually work in this case. If you try the same with Lync 2010 client, you get an OperationPendingException, but still ...

Comment: Re. your form creation problem, I don't know what error you got exactly, but you should access UI only from UI thread and it might as well be that ConversationAdded handler is running off another thread.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you running your application from? I had a very similar stacktrace and moving the application into "C:\Users\MyUser" resolved the problem for me.

Comment: C:\User\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\My Project